# Can nonpaged memory in guest OS be paged out in Windows Hyper-V?

Tags: windows, virtualization, hyper-v

Say I am writing a kernel driver and it is running in Windows in a Hyper-V child partition, there are some buffers from non-paged pool.  Is this buffer guaranteed to be locked in physical memory of the host?

The background is that I would like to initiate DMA involving this buffer and I don't want the host to page it out.

Answer (score 0):

Answering my own question.
Based on an answer I got from someone on the Hyper-V team, he said the following:

> Generally speaking, memory that is non-paged from a guest’s
>   perspective can be paged out by the host.  However, if the guest has
>   access to a physical device, the host will not page guest memory to
>   avoid causing a DMA fault at the IOMMU.  Whether the guest is Windows
>   or Linux (or something else) is not a factor in this behavior.